# How Aggregations are calculated internally in single node or multi-node Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate

I read Elasticsearch doc., I know the APIs and Query DSLs of Elasticsearch. I could also find documentation of how query results are fetched from Elasticsearch But how are aggregates calculated efficiently on any query internally?

Answer (score 5):

Elasticsearch processes searches (queries) and aggregations in the same way: scatter, then gather.

The first node to receive an incoming request will act as the coordinating node. The coordinating node's job is to parse the request, then route it as necessary (if necessary). For routing, it depends on what is happening, but for a query or an aggregation, it's necessary to go to the shards of all indices being used.

Imagine a three node cluster:

- `node1`
- `node2`
- `node3`

If you have *two* indices with 2 shards and 1 replica (`2 * (2 + (2 * 1))` total shards, which is 8), then a simple layout could be:

- `node1` has index0_shard0p, index0_shard1r, index1_shard1r
- `node2` has index0_shard0r, index0_shard1p, index1_shard0p
- `node3` has index1_shard0r, index1_shard1p

(Note: it is not completely balanced, but that's okay)

If `node2` happens to receive a request to aggregate results for *both* indices, then it becomes the coordinating node for that request. It then:

1. Checks the cluster state to understand where those index shards live.
2. Chooses, practically arbitrarily, whether to use a primary versus a replica for each given shard.
3. Sends out the query phase.
4. Receives the shard-by-shard results.
5. Combines the results (e.g., finding the real top 10 out of each shard's top 10).
6. Sends out the fetch phase (get the actual documents from the shards that have them).
7. Sends the response back to you.

The query, then fetch phase as it's known is how the magic happens. It also implies that the query phase is working with extra data compared to what you actually want *because* shards don't know what exists on the other shards. This is discussed in the [`terms` aggregation documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) in great detail and you should check it out.